# fetch latest files from Sftp server by powershell

Tags: powershell, sftp

I have a situation where I need to find latest flies on directories on SFTP servers and if files are persisted in the directories then email triggered. I am trying to get this by Powershell with POSH-SSH module. but i am not getting this.

it will very helpful for me to give some info or help on this.

this should be in Powershell only and with SFTP no FTP.

Comment: What is your _PowerShell_ Command-Line?

Comment: Basically I am trying to imp this. as of now, I am trying to fetch files name but it gives me directory name as well. $getfiles =@(Get-SFTPChildItem $sessionTest -Path $sourceTest | select FullName). is any way to get files to name without directory name

Comment: I see a Note, @Rajesh, that states that "_The –Directory, -File, -Attributes, -Hidden, and –System switches were added to Get-ChildItem cmdlet in Windows PowerShell 3.0_". Maybe you can negate the `-Directory` Switch somehow.

Comment: In the situation when the `Get-SFTPChildItem` Command-Let has absolutely nothing to do with the `Get-ChildItem` Command-Let and its Output provides only the `FullName` Line, then I guess that you verily have nothing else to do than to parse the Unqualified File Name by yourself.

Comment: See also [Downloading yesterday files in PowerShell using WinSCP](https://superuser.com/q/1189111/213663).